# How to draw outer and inner border in kendo donut chart

Tags: kendo-chart

I wanted to draw border around Kendo donut chart. is there any options available to achieve the same. For detail please refer attached image.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution and I am posting the answer if someone wants the same functionalities.
we can override default series visual

```
this.$('.chartview').kendoChart({
series.visual = this.overrideSeries.bind(this),
...

});

funtion overrideSeries(e){
      let origin = e.center;
      let radius = e.radius;
      var draw = kendo.drawing;
      var geom = kendo.geometry;

      var circleGeometryOuter = new geom.Circle(origin, radius + 5);
      var circleOuter = new draw.Circle(circleGeometryOuter).stroke(CssConst.DONUT_BORDER_COLOR, .5);

      var circleGeometryInner = new geom.Circle(origin, radius - 5);
      var circleInner = new draw.Circle(circleGeometryInner).stroke('#cdcdcd', .5);

      var visual = new draw.Group();

      visual.append(circleOuter, e.createVisual(), circleInner); 
    return visual
}
```